# How does video on demand work in Youtube?

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, html5-video, webm

I am trying to understand how Video On Demand works on Youtube. I found out that my browser is downloading many WebM files. When I download one of the WebM video chunk and try to play it on Chrome it does not play.

Can you explain how WebM works with youtube? I read that there needs to be initialization and clusters. What is the file extension for the initialization file for WebM videos? Does cluster refer to many .webm files?

From my basic understanding,

Click on a youtube video -> Youtube sends initialization file -> Once browser downloads and accepts the file, the browser request 1st chunk .webm video file and play it -> request the second chunk.

Is this correct?

Comment: something like https://permadi.com/2010/06/webm-file-structure/ might give you a starter, but not really sure what you are trying to do, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did more studying over the weekend and realized that I need more learning to do in terms of Codecs, and Containers. Thanks for directing me to the right direction. For someone who is interested: http://write.flossmanuals.net/a-look-at-open-video/understanding-codecs-and-containers/